# why webservice inserting blank value in database?

Tags: php, soap-client

> Here is my PHP code, when I execute this, it insert null values in database, why ? please help

```
    <?php
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');
 try {
$soap = new soapclient("http://arpitgupta.srdtkstore.com/service/webservice.asmx?WSDL" ,array("trace"=>1,"exceptions"=>1));

$data=array( 'reqid' =>  '4444','username' => 'hhghg');

$return=$soap->call('getValue',$data);


print_r($return);

}
catch(SoapFault $e)
{
 echo $e;
}
?>
```

Comment: Do the fields exists? Are the field-names spelled correct?

Comment: Where is your code for insert. What is the outout of the `print_r($return)`?